# How to receive arrays through WebHttpBinding?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, arrays, webhttpbinding

Will anything like

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string IWannaRead(int[] ids);
```

work? And how to form a link\url (`www.example.com/service.svc?ids=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`) for the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. It works exactly as you specified.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/2341c11e-92b3-4da4-aba5-858054f46c80